# Best way to generate unique numbers from given two sets of numbers

Tags: math

I have two groups. And each group contains a list of non-repeating numbers. But a number can appear in both groups. Each group has a value assigned to it (shown in parens below). I need to combine the numbers from both groups into a third group and manipulate the numbers in such a way that the third group also has non repeating numbers. The third group will have total number of elements equal to the total from group 1 and group 2.

Group A (10): 1, 2, 4
Group B (20): 1, 4, 5

So if I want to create Group c making sure that it doesn't have any repeating numbers one strategy that doesn't work is to use the Group value. So for example if I multiple the value of the group with the number within it it can cause collision in the third group

After multiplication I'll get 10, 20, 40, 20, 80, 100 for group C but we now have 20 in the new group twice.

Is there a simple strategy I'm not thinking of?

Comment: If the numbers are always positive, find the max value in the first group and add it to the values in the second group.

Comment: If the numbers are furthermore positive integers and the group number confined to a range, e.g. 1 - 100,, add group number divided by max range, so: 1.10, 2.10, 4.10, 1.20,  4.20, 5.20.

Comment: "_and manipulate the numbers in such a way...._" -- that is a very broad description; are there any more specific constraints or requirements? What kinds of manipulation are allowed? And what is the meaning of the "group value"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this should be posted on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going with GriffeyDog's answer

If the numbers are always positive, find the max value in the first group and add it to the values in the second group